# Combine Two Formulas in Separate Cells Into One Cell

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

In Excel, I have been asked to combine two formulas into one cell and to do this across 850 cells. Where one cell is pulling from a specific cell from another worksheet like `='Acquisition'!G32` and the other formula is like the following 
`=SUMIFS('Inputs'!$I:$I,'Inputs'!$C:$C,$C6,'Inputs'!$D:$D,F$4)`
The goal is to have one formula like
 `='Acquisition'!G32 + SUMIFS('Inputs'!$I:$I,'Inputs'!$C:$C,$C6,'Inputs'!$D:$D,F$4)`

Is there an Excel function or some code that I can write to do this? The problem is the reference to very specific cells so I can't do it once and drag my formulas across my range.

I have tried many Excel functions such as Cell, Concatenate, Offset, and a few others, but I can't combine the formulas into one cell. I am only able to get the output from each formula into one cell.

The goal is to go from: =formula1 = formula2 -> =formula1 + formula2

Comment: Why is *the reference to very specific cells* a problem that cannot be solved by using a proper addressing mode?

Comment: I am not sure what you are referring to, I tried the Address function, but I could not get the cell references.

Comment: To rephrase: What would you like the result to be when you *"drag my formulas across my range."*? Be very specific.

Answer (score -1):

You could use the `openpyxl` module in Python to do that, using something like this:

```py
import openpyxl

import os

# Change working directory
mydir = ("YOUR_PATH")
os.chdir(mydir)
    
fname = "Book1.xlsx" # the filename of the file

# Opening the workbook
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename = fname, 
                            data_only = False) # False because we want formulas

ws_names = wb.sheetnames # getting the sheet names

ws = wb[ws_names[0]] # setting ws to be the first sheet

# loop over cells
for i in range(1, 9):
    
    # combine cell formulas and assign to new cell
    ws.cell(i,4).value = (ws.cell(i,2).value + 
                          " + " + 
                          ws.cell(i,3).value)[1:] # [1:] to remove the '='

# save updated workbook to new file
wb.save('NewBook.xlsx')
```

This example would loop over the first 8 rows, and put a formula in column D that was the sum of the formulas in columns B and C.